# Track field dependency with features

Tags: 7, features

I modified a field dependency on my `Call` content type. Features did not track the change automatically. I cannot figure out how to manually add it to features.

[image: screen shot of field dependencies on call content type]

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to it:

- Add the *feature exportable* manually to the *module.info*.
- You can check the available features with the `drush features-list` command. You have to find the *field dependency* format within that list, it could be a variable that looks like your field name.
- If you *module.info* has the new *field dependency*, you can update the feature `drush fu myfeature_module`
- Then review the generated files, maybe with `git diff`. You should see the change.

I am not sure what an exported *field dependency* looks like, there are different formats, these are examples so that you have an idea of what it would look like:

```
features[ctools][] = field_group:field_group:1

features[ctools][] = strongarm:strongarm:1

features[features_api][] = api:2

features[field_base][] = field_image

features[field_group][] = group_teaser|node

features[field_instance][] = node-about_page-field_image

features[node][] = about_page

features[variable][] = comment_about_page
```

Comment: I think you're talking about module dependencies. I'm asking about field dependencies on a content type (the field dependency determines when the field is visible to a user).